# What’s the difference between “the using of this machine” and “using my neighbour’s wifi”?

Tags: definite-articles, gerunds, gerund-phrases, deverbal-nouns

Please consider these two different sentences*:

1. I am aware of ***the* using of this machine**.
2. I am accused of **using my neighbour’s wifi**.

Why do we use the article *the* before the *using* in the first sentence, but we don’t use an article before in the second sentence?

It’s the same gerund in both cases: the word *using*. So how can in some cases a gerund takes an article, but in other cases that same gerund does not take an article?

Comment: Answer: We **don't** use _the_ in the first sentence, because the first sentence is ungrammatical. In the second sentence the gerund phrase is the object of the preposition _of_, which is required by _accuse_ when mentioning the offense.

Comment: @JohnLawler There's nothing ungrammatical about the first sentence. The boss may call his subordinates together to complain about inappropriate use of the company's copier: *I am aware of **the** using of this machine after hours and for personal reasons.* *Use* is much more popular than *using* in this context, but the intertubes attests to the using of the latter.

Comment: And "using" in your second example is a verb, not a noun, and verbs can't take an article.  You can tall that it's a verb because of the following direct object -- nouns cannot have direct objects without "of".

Comment: The main thing is that the noun "use" exists, so there is no need to resort to the gerundal noun "using", and hence it's not idiomatic.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/497286/2085).

Answer (score 2):

## Gerunds are only ever verbs, never nouns

I think your mistake is pretending that any word that ends in *-ing*  and which is derived from a verb is a “gerund”. This is not true. To be a gerund, it must be verb. And the first one is not:*using* is not gerund in first sentence. It’s only a noun—a deverbal noun, if you prefer. Nouns do noun things like taking articles, adjectives, and prepositional phrases.

For example, here *taming* is a noun only, not a verb, and therefore not a gerund:

- the quick taming of the shrew

You can tell it’s a noun not a verb because it’s doing noun things only, and it’s not doing verb things.

In contrast, here *taming* is indeed a verb with none of the customary nominal appurtenances:

- quickly taming the shrew

This time *taming*  takes an adverb not an adjective, has a direct-object argument, and accepts no article.  That makes it a verb, not a noun. It is therefore a gerund. The other one is not.

## But entire gerund *phrases* can replace entire noun *phrases*

A gerund phrase is a kind of non-finite verb phrase that is able to do the job of a noun phrase, including serving as the a clause’s subject and as a verb’s object complement or a prepositional object.

- **Quickly taming the shrew** is your best strategy. (*gerund phrase as subject of copular verb*)
- I recommend **quickly taming the shrew**. (*gerund phrase as direct object of the verb*)
- By **quickly taming the shrew**, you have restored tranquility in our household. (*gerund phrase as prepositional object*)

Those are gerunds, so only verbs not nouns.  And those gerund phrases are not nouns, either, because you cannot do a noun thing to a gerund phrase even though a gerund phrase can itself do a noun-phrase thing.  You have to look at these as replaceable constituents.

The other construction has no verb in it at all. It’s just a regular old noun phrase, not a gerund phrase.

- **The quick taming of this shrew** is your best strategy. (*noun phrase as subject of copular verb*)
- I recommend **the quick taming of this shrew**. (*noun phrase as direct object of the verb*)
- By **the quick taming of this shrew**, you have restored tranquility in our household. (*noun phrase as prepositional object*)

Comment: What about "The use of" or "The usage of"?

Comment: Would you care to check this question https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/316094/9683

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/497286/2085).